# Java Socket why server can not reply client

Tags: java, sockets

I wanna write the code to let Client send a string to Server, Server print the string and reply a string, then Client print the string Server reply.
My Server

```
public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket ss = null;
    Socket s = null;
    try {
        ss = new ServerSocket(34000);
        s = ss.accept();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                s.getInputStream()));
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream());

        while (true) {
            String string = in.readLine();
            if (string != null) {
                System.out.println("br: " + string);

                if (string.equals("end")) {
                    out.write("to end");
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    System.out.println("end");
                    // break;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        s.close();
        ss.close();
    }
}
}
```

My Client:

```
public class Client {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Socket socket =null;


    try {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 34000);
        BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

        String string = "";
        string = "end";
        out.write(string);
        out.flush();
        while(true){
            String string2 = in.readLine();
            if(string2.equals("to end")){
                System.out.println("yes sir");
                break;
            }
        }


    }  catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            System.out.println("closed client");
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
}
```

are there some somethings wrong? if i remove the code "while(true) ..." in client class, it's OK.

Comment: so can you explain what is happening

Comment: Do you send a newLine?

Comment: "public String readLine()
Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed." -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

Comment: When your server is reading newline `in.readLine()`, you can use the following in client:
`PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);`
`out.println(string);`

Comment: Your code is wrong. If `readLine()` returns `null` you must close the socket and exit the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should add `"\r\n"` at the end of the String which write into stream.

example:

client :

```
    string = "end";
    out.write(string + "\r\n");
    out.flush();
```

server :

```
    out.write("to end" + "\r\n");
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    System.out.println("end");
                // break;
```

Comment: I try, and it work well in ecplise.Can you tell me what is your IDE and what kind of OS

Comment: It doesn't work in mt case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63127834

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the server response.
You do a

```
System.out.println("br: " + string);
```

but not a

```
out.write(string);
out.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Appand "\n" to end of the response from server.

```
outToClient.writeBytes(sb.toString() + "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading lines but you aren't writing lines. Add a newline, or call `BufferedReader.newLine().`